# SQL Sum of 3 counts (different month clause) from same table

Tags: sql, count, sum

I have tried this a few different ways and it never seems to work:

```
SUM(
  Select count(*) from table1 where month = 1 +
  Select count(*) from table1 where month = 2 +
  Select count(*) from table1 where month = 3
)
```

What is the proper way to do it? SUM(IF(case)) also didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this do what you want?

```
SELECT
COUNT(*)
FROM
Table1
WHERE month in (1,2,3)
```

Comment: And that was the embarrassing over-complication of the century on my part, cheers mate.

Comment: Happens to us all. Sometimes you just can't see the forest for the trees.